# The convergence of the fixed-point iteration for solving a cubic equation

Tags: polynomials, convergence-divergence, numerical-methods, roots

I have a third-grade polynomial of the form $Ax^3+Bx+C$ and I want to find its roots. I cannot use Gauss to guess the first root and it is not trivial, so I try this:

$0=Ax^3+Bx+C$

and for a given root $X_0$:

$X_0=(-AX_0^3-C)/B$

I then guess that $X_0 = 3$ (just an example), then find a new value of $X$ until it converges to something near $3.54$. Sometimes when I'm not lucky it diverges.

I assume there must be a criterion to decide whether or not $X_0$ is a good approximation in the sense that it will converge to the root.

Comment: How lovely. I was hoping a bot could tell me how to do just that!

Comment: What you are doing here is called *Fixed Point Iteration*, solving $g(x)=x$ using $x_{n+1}=g(x_n)$. You can find lots of information under that name.

Comment: Fair enough! I'm glad that exists and wasn't just a fluke. I'll look it up. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome. I feel guilty, because there *are* useful criteria for determining whether the fixed point iteration with given initial estimate will converge, but it would take a while to write  things down even in the context of cubics. Roughly speaking, if we are using the iteration $x_{n+1}=g(x_n)$, and there is a symmetric  interval about the root and a constant $k\lt 1$ such that $|g'(x)|\lt k$ in that interval, then any initial value within that interval will give convergence.

Comment: Great! That's a good start point. I'll look further into it. Thanks a lot!